# Handling Lost Internet Connection Android While fetching the data from the server

Tags: android, performance, android-asynctask, broadcastreceiver

I am in a keen interest to know the procedure to handle the following scenario, If it can be done, I am sure it will help a lot of developers in their work:-

Scenario: Suppose I just check availability of Internet Connection before starting a Asynctask and it was available. Now suppose as soon as after 3 seconds the connectivity is lost or just you can say that I have turned off the Internet, then what should one can do here to **handle it IMMEDIATELY** ?

I have just registered a broadcast receiver to handle the network connections:-

```
public class HotspotConnectionChecker extends BroadcastReceiver {
    Context context;
    SharedPreferences loginPref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor;
    String username,password;
    boolean isLoggedIn;

    //One Empty Constructor is required
    public HotspotConnectionChecker() {
    }

    public HotspotConnectionChecker(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager =  (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        NetworkInfo mobileNetInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

        if(activeNetInfo!=null){
            Toast.makeText( context, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }
        else if(activeNetInfo==null){
            Toast.makeText( context, "No/Bad Network Connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }
    }
}
```

**But, unable to get how to use it in my scenario, there may numerous numbers of asynctasks being working in different activities.**

Please suggest or give me simple means to solve or overcome these type of problems.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to handle it one place only. because if you want to notify all the activities then also you will use a broadcast receiver. So solution is register a broadcast receiver inside the doInBackGround method and unregister it inside onPostExecuteMethod.